# Get department wise employee details and edit employee details

Tags: c#, .net, gridview

I have one problem in gridview controls.

I am using two tables employee and department. I want to get department name wise employee details and we can also edit that employee details.
I have take listview within gridview but in that case I cannot handle inner gridview events.
How can I do solve this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You could write a query using Query Builder to display e.g. department name with employee details. Something like this:

```
SELECT tblEmployee.EmpId, tblDepartment.DeptId, tblDepartment.DeptName, tblEmployee.Surname 
FROM (tblDepartment INNER JOIN tblEmploye ON tblEmployee.EmpId = tblDepartment.EmpId)
```

To be able to edit that query that is bound to a GridView (AccessDataSource), you have to configure your query respectively to the columns of GridWiew. E.g.

```
UPDATE [tblEmployee] SET [Surname] = ?, [DeptId] = ? WHERE [EmpId] = ?  (your GridView column order is Surname, DeptId, EmpId)
```

To improve the display convert the field (DepId) to the template and add drop down list